# Can "DVI-D out" sometimes provide a video signal to a 15-pin D-Sub VGA CRT via simple connector (or dongle)?

Tags: cable, connector, video-conversion, crt, dongle

My motherboard (GIGABYTE GA-G41M-ES2H) has 3 video output ports

```
# 1 x D-Sub port  
# 1 x DVI-D port (Note 3)  
# 1 x HDMI port  

(Note 3) The DVI-D port does not support D-Sub connection by adapter.
```

Does this mean that in some situations, a DVI-D port **can** provide a video signal to a D-Sub connector?

I vaguely remember reading something about this, which said it was possible, but without audio.

Is it possible to get a DVI-D to D-Sub connector? ...and if so, why would it **not** work on this particular motherboard?

Comment: The "V" in "DVI" stands for "video". There is never any audio. You're probably confusing this with HDMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D` in `DVI-D` stands for *digital*. There are `DVI-D`, `DVI-A` (analog) and (probably most commonly) `DVI-I` (integrated, i.e. both).

You need analog (`I` or `A`) for the adaptor to work. It doesn't work here, because it's `D`. They probably provide the note to reduce tech support work load.

Answer (score 2):

No. DVI-I provides both analog and digital signals, but DVI-D **only** provides the digital signal.